# Lucene.net - how to query a path filed with numeric sections?

Tags: indexing, lucene.net

I've created an index which indexes the event items in different sections of a website. 
This items are on the website in a structure like this:

```
/Start/Section1/Events/2011/12/25/X-mas
/Start/Section2/Events/2012/01/01/New-years-day
```

These paths are stored in the field `path` in the index.

On the start page I need an overview of the events from all the different sections. 
When I'm in a section I only need the events placed under that section.

I add a booleanquery like this:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("path", analyzer);
Query query = queryParser.Parse(startPath);
completeQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

"path" is a field that is added through a custom index script;

To retreive the items for the start page I would search my index using:

```
string startPath = "/Start";
```

This normally gives me all item where the path starts with "/Start"

To retreive the items for section1 I would search my index using:

```
string startPath = "/Start/Section1/Events";
```

This normally gives me all item where the path starts with "/Start/Section1/Events"

I've implemented this solution for news items and that works fine. For event items it does not. 
When I search my index it returns no hits. The problem is that the last three folder names are numeric.
When I rename the folders (f.e. 2011,12,25) to text (two-thousand,twelve,twenty-five) it DOES return hits.

How can I get my index to return results keeping my folder names numeric?

Comment: what type of analyzer are you using? This should work with the `StandardAnalyzer` imo

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CharTokenizer` for your path,  and have `IsTokenChar(char c)` return false for the `/`.

This way you'll be sure each part of your path is an individual `Token`.